# Possible to guarantee ember-cli addon hook run order?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Is there a document (or a test) that guarantees the run order of addon hooks?

I need to do work in both `config` and `included`, but they run in different orders depending on environment.

With `ember serve` it is `config` -> `included` -> `config`. But `ember test` runs them as `included` -> `config`.

I’m wondering if I rely on `config` running at least once after `included` if that will keep working.

More details:
I'm working on https://github.com/FortAwesome/ember-fontawesome/issues/57 the problem we have is that there are some configuration options that are needed at build time and at run time. We currently have configuration in both `environment.js` and `ember-cli-config.js` and want to consolidate into a single place.

The correct place to read configuration and initialize empty values seems to be the `config` hook, but the correct place to work with that data is in the `included` hook.

Furthermore we need to provide deprecation notices on the old configuration location and a smooth upgrade path.

Comment: Could you describe what it is you are trying to achieve? Could be that a different more suitable approach exists.

Comment: Sure! I think I've done that now. Thanks.